# How do I get support for Azure at the "free" level?

Tags: azure, azure-management

[This link says](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/?WT.mc_id=Support_Plan_510979) that web incidents are supported at the Free level, however, when I try [to open a case using the web support](https://portal.azure.com/?r=1#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade) at  I am presented with the form below to fill out... and I'm unable to proceed.

How do I, as a consumption user, not a MSDN user, get free web support?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At free level only support for billing and subscription management-related issues is available.

So if you selected a category other than billing or subscription at first step, it will not allow you to submit a request without a support plan.

If you're looking for technical support your best bet is to submit your question here on stackoverflow or msdn forums; or buy a support plan.

Comment: IF my technical support question relates to a borked provisiong process that requires escalation, (e.g. an instance perpetually in pending) then go to the forums?  I dislike that policy since I'm already a paying customer of MSFT

Comment: raise a request as billing or subscription support. I've successfully resolved my provisioning issues by raising in one of those categories.